# jQuery fadeIn combine

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to variables

```
var $aa = $('#Adiv').find('li').has('class');
var $bb = $('#Bdiv');
```

Both variables need `fadeIn()`

```
$aa.fadeIn();
$bb.fadeIn();
```

if they have same action, are we able to combine one line?
like `$aa+$bb.fadeIn();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to combine the results of 2 different jQuery objects, so

```
$aa.add($bb).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Which is the jquery version?

Comment: @SSS it is there from jQuery 1.3.2

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
$('#Adiv,#Bdiv').fadeIn();
```

Comment: Thanks! was clear, but  if `var $aa = $('#Adiv').find('li').has('class');` it doesnt work well.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to the elements you want to fadein. then you can do this:

```
$('.className').fadeIn();
```